# How do I extract data from a column in csv file in python in relation to the row it's in?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from a csv file that look something like this:

```
ID,Name,Grade
23,Abby,A
56,Amy,D
13,Kate,C
74,Peter,B
45,Mike,D
19,Sev,D
48,Lily,C
30,Harry,F
```

I have folders set up by the order of the grade. I want to scan the csv file and extract the information and place each name as a subfolder under the corresponding grade folder. I want the end result to look something like this:

[image: This is done manually]

I am planning on using pandas for this, and all I have right now is this:

```
# Open file 
with open('Students.csv') as file_obj:
      
    # Create reader object by passing the file 
    # object to reader method
    reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
      
    # Iterate over each row in the csv 
    # file using reader object
    for row in reader_obj:
        print(row)
```

I know this is really vague, but I really don't know how to make it better.

Comment: Did some of the given answers help you? You may accept/upvote or leave a comment there.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need pandas for this.  A simple dictionary will do it.

```
import csv
      
reader_obj = csv.reader(open('x.csv'))
grades = {
    'A':[],
    'B':[],
    'C':[],
    'D':[],
    'F':[]
}

for row in reader_obj:
    if row[0] == 'ID':
        continue
    grades[row[2]].append( row[1] )

for k,v in grades.items():
    print(k)
    for name in v:
        print("   ",name)
```

Output:

```
A
    Abby
B
    Peter
C
    Kate
    Lily
D
    Amy
    Mike
    Sev
F
    Harry
```

You could simplify this using a `defaultdict`, but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

At the time you call `print`, `row[0]` is the id, `row[1]`is the name, and `row[2]` is the grade. Now work out a function that takes a name and a grade as arguments, and creates the corresponding directory; call it instead of `print`, and you’re done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module to parse the CSV, and then use the `os` module to create the subdirectories:

```py
import os
import csv
import itertools

with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
    grades = set(row["Grade"] for row in data)

    for grade in grades:
        os.mkdir(grade)

    for row in data:
        os.mkdir(f"{row['Grade']}{os.path.sep}{row['Name']}")
```

This produces the desired directory structure:

[image]